# Fetching a single model in backbone, why doesn't this work?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, backbone-model

m is a subclass of Backbone.Model. I would expect m.url() to return '/api/media/sources/1' but instead I get:

```
> m.id
1
> m.collection.url
"/api/media/sources"
> m.urlRoot
undefined
> m.url()
"/api/media/sources"
```

What's going on?

Comment: Can you show your model's `idAttribute` and the result of calling `isNew()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you want the `id` to be appended to the URL, you should set `urlRoot`, not `url`.

Take a look at the [default implementation for `Backbone.Model.prototype.url`](http://backbonejs.org/docs/backbone.html#section-69) and it will make sense:

```
url: function() {
  var base =
    _.result(this, 'urlRoot') ||
    _.result(this.collection, 'url') ||
    urlError();
  if (this.isNew()) return base;
  return base.replace(/([^\/])$/, '$1/') + encodeURIComponent(this.id);
},
```

---

Later comments revealed (after this answer was posted) that the problem had to do with how the attributes were being set.

In general, you should always use `model.set("id", idValue)` for all attribute changes, even and especially the ID attribute. (If you have set `idAttribute` to something else on the model prototype, use that name as the first argument instead of `"id"`.)

More generally still, it's a bad idea to access `model.attributes` directly- use `model.set()` and `model.get()` instead. The `model.id` property is a convenience that you should basically treat as read-only; Backbone will modify it appropriately in every `set()` call that involves the id attribute. –  Platinum Azure 18 hours ago

Comment: Ah, collection.url should work just as well as urlRoot, but this code shows the real problem: the id is not appended if isNew() returns true. Even though m.id was set, m.attributes.id wasn't, and it turns out you need to set both.

Comment: Ah, yes. In general, you should always use `model.set("id", idValue)` for all attribute changes, even and especially the ID attribute. (If you have set `idAttribute` to something else on the model prototype, use that name as the first argument instead of `"id"`.)

Comment: And in general, it's a bad idea to access `model.attributes` directly- use `model.set()` and `model.get()` instead. The `model.id` property is a convenience that you should basically treat as read-only; Backbone will modify it appropriately in every `set()` call that involves the id attribute.

Comment: Yes, model.id is what confused me, I was trying to set it directly. Now that I set() it, things work as expected.